# Multiprocessing logging: Lock vs Queue

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

## Background

I was planning to use [`logging.handler.RotatingFileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler), and I’m logging from multiple processes using `multiprocessing`.

I've seen many recommendations to use [`multiprocessing.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) and a listener process to serialize the logging.

## Question

What is the advantage of using a Queue over wrapping logging functions within a mutex with [`multiprocessing.Lock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock)? It seems like most (if not all) recommendations have been towards the Queue, but I haven't seen any real explanations why.

Comment: Your alternative plan is a bit unclear.  Were you thinking of writing concurrently to the same log file from multiple processes, using a `multiprocessing.Lock()` to serialize access to that file?

Comment: Yes, that was my line of thought.

Answer (score 2):

## Queues

The advantage of using a queue is that your processes’ logging calls are non-blocking. Additionally, the queue (with a single worker thread) keeps log messages’ generation order in the log file.

---

## Locks

### Non-blocking locks

If you want to use Locks with non-blocking behavior, the lock must be acquired in a non-blocking mode. To do so, log messages must be buffered by each subprocess. This adds unnecessary complexity, and can introduce delays before log messages are saved, resulting in a wrong order of messages.

### Blocking locks

If you want to use Locks in blocking mode, then your subprocesses don’t need local queues when you acquire the lock. But then, this blocks code execution. This is usually undesirable behavior, since logging is expected to be very fast.